# Passing multiple variable to Redux Action creator. What format?

Tags: react-redux

I am pretty new to Redux but I am getting a good hang of it so far.
I am setting up an actions file and I would need to pass two values to payload.

Please let me know if the question has already been asked elsewhere and I missed it.

Thanks!
kramnic

p.s. below is what I have drafted

```js
    export const transferValues = (fromId, toId) => {
      return {
        type: VALUES_TRANSFER,
        payload: { fromId, toId }, //should it be array? not sure about syntax here
      };
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also have an action of type `{ type: string, fromId: number, toId: number }` instead of a single "payload". that's a matther of preference I think. you just need to adapt you reducers accordingly. I personally like the above attempt more because it represents single attributes like I have them in my state as well. so I can do like a one-to-one mapping. for example:

```js
// state
export type SessionState = {
  +id: number,
  +username: string,
  +sessionId: string,
}

// reducer here
[...]
    case SET_USERNAME:
      const setUsernameAction = ((action: any): SetUsernameAction)

      return {
        ...state,
        username: setUsernameAction.username,
        sessionId: setUsernameAction.sessionId,
      }
[...]

// example action
export const setUsername = (username: string, sessionId: string): SetUsernameAction => {
  return { type: SET_USERNAME, username, sessionId }
}
```

but you will certainly never use an array for multiple attributes. you'll lose the named access to properties as well as any chance to type your action. stick with objects, no matther what solution you'll go for.

Comment: I see, yes that would also work as a solution. Thank you! in my case, to adapt my code to your suggestion, would this work:

```
      export const transferValues = (fromId, toId) => {
      return {
        type: VALUES_TRANSFER,
         fromId: fromId,
 toId: toId }
      };
    };
```

Comment: no problem. yes, that works. althought it is not that clean. js is a very smart language - it's enought to write `export const transferValues = (fromId, toId) => { return { type: VALUES_TRANSFER, fromId, toId } }; };` (without explicitly naming the return parameters).